# Programming logic - update the database only one time after specific time interval

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic

I am developing ecommerce store in php and I have some problem in creating a logic. The problem is I have a store page where I am showing some products. all the products have some time interval,after interval passes the products will no longer be display there.

For example

Product: jeans
time left: 10 days.

after 10 days **jeans** product will no longer be there. in database I have a set a field with the name **active_status** which accepts Y or N..

I know that I can simply run the update query and set the status to "N"  after time passes. here in this example after 10 days 
BUT the question is WHEN DO I RUN THIS UPDATE QUERY ? 
should I always check time and run again and again update query and set STATUS TO 'N'??? IS that is the only solution ?

I mean usually we do like for example if customer logins we set some status or any other event but here we are setting the status against checking the time. Hopefully you have understand my question

In the db I am saving the start time and number of days which user puts through the admin panel

Comment: So do you store `expire_date` for a product and if so then you can easily select those where current date is less than expire date.

Comment: How do you show "10 days" left ? Do you store it in DB or calculate using dates ?

Comment: I am calculating using dates

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you don't understand the question. the question is when do I run this query ? on what condition I run this query.. their is no event is going to happen from the user side.

Answer (score 0):

My first shot would be cron, php script and properties table (if needed, because for simple uses you could just store expiration date inside business entity).

1. Cron runs php script periodically (e.g. once a day),
2. scripts checks if there is anything to delete, based on properties table, or entity properties.
3. If there is anything to delete, script performs deletion of selected content.

That's all and it is in fact very popular scenario.

More on cron: http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my logic i hope it will helps i think

While Publishing the product we have to maintain the time interval of that product for example if you want to display the product for 10 days give 10 days and date of publish product.

By comparing with that date and number of days given for time interval with the present date i.e today's date

Can you check with this